# How can I use firebase storage to download images in a file and show them in a table view?

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui

Good afternoon,

I have been stuck on this problem for months. I am trying to use firebase storage to save image files that a user uploaded. The program should then be able to update the queue and show the image in a horizontal table view. Kinda like netflix where its titles of movies/shows but mine would just be pictures. After trying to figure this out, this is what I came up with. Here is to receive the images

```
class ImageRecieve : ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var songImageArrayURL = [URL]()
    @Published var data : Data?
    @Published var songImage : NSImage?
    @Published var AlbumCoverArray = [NSImage]()
        func GetURLS(){
            //we want to get the download urls
                  bfRef.listAll { (result, error) in
                      if let error = error{ //if theres an error, print it
                          print(error.localizedDescription)
                      }
                      let prefixes = result.prefixes
                      //loop to search each song prefix
                      for i in prefixes.indices{
                        //get the song of each prefix
                          prefixes[i].listAll { (result, error) in
                              if let error = error {
                                  print(error.localizedDescription)
                              }
                              else {
                                  let items = result.items
                                //if anything contains ".mp3" dont add it to array.
                                for j in items.indices{
                                    if(!items[j].name.contains("mp3")){
                                        SongImage.append(items[j])
                                        self.download(SongImage: items[j])
                                    }
                                }
                                
                            }
                          }
                    }
                }
        }
        
    func download(SongImage:StorageReference){
                //get download url
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                SongImage.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                    if let error = error { //if there is an error print it
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                    else {
                        if(url != nil){
                            self.songImage = NSImage(byReferencing: url!)
                            self.AlbumCoverArray.append(self.songImage!)
                            }
                        }
                    }
    }
}
    
    func load(){
        if(self.songImageArrayURL.isEmpty){
            GetURLS()
        }
        print(self.songImageArrayURL)
        for i in self.songImageArrayURL.indices{
            print(self.songImageArrayURL[i])
            DispatchQueue.global().async{
                if let data =  try? Data(contentsOf: self.songImageArrayURL[i]){
                    if let image = NSImage(data:data){
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.songImage = image
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    func cancel(){
    }
}
```

here is to load the images :

```
struct LoadImages<Placeholder: View>: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var loader : ImageRecieve
    private var placeholder : Placeholder?
    
    init(placeholder: Placeholder? = nil) {
        loader = ImageRecieve()
        self.placeholder = placeholder
    }
    
    var body: some View {
         image
            .onAppear(perform: loader.GetURLS)
             .onDisappear(perform: loader.cancel)
        
        
     }
     
     private var image: some View{
        ForEach(loader.AlbumCoverArray.indices,id:\.self){
            i in
            Group{
                if(self.loader.songImage != nil){
                    Image(nsImage:self.loader.AlbumCoverArray[i]).resizable().frame(width:50, height:50)
                }
                else{
                    self.placeholder
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the problem I've been stuck on is that the photos are only downloading one at a time and not listing one by one. For example, they show one image and then switch to the next. I would like an array of images. So that the images get added to the list. I've tried using an image array but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

> photos are only downloading one at a time and not listing one by one.

in all languages an array/list is processed sequentially, you might want to use multi-Threading for parallelism. use a queue and assign few threads which download image, after each download pop the element from queue.

all the child threads append/push the data to the main thread. in that manner you will be able to display images as they load.

PS:i am != swiftie but seeing your programming i sense turmoil. try improving your code grammar and avoid too many functions and spaces.

Comment: Thank you! I will look this up, I'm actually used to C++ so I'm relatively new to swiftui. But thank you so much for guiding me! What do you use to program and would you recommend switching since im not completely used to it yet?

Comment: python has good multi threading but has the GIL (global interpreter Lock) may cause some consequences. But as far as i know swift is the only go to option for apple ecosystem, objective C is dead. even i use firebase but i develop web apps so that they can be both run on IOS or android via browser.